# How to manage Flyway password rotation without version conflict

Tags: spring-boot, flyway

I have a Flyway migration script that creates a role with a password. This password is retrieved from AWS secretsmanager. The issue I face is if the value in secrets manager is updated I obviously get password incorrect error when the user tried to connect to database.

Since writing sql.statements altering the role and updating the password everytime the password is rotated in AWS is not acceptable, can you please suggest how do I manage this seamlessly.